# Inequality in three variables $ \frac{3-(xy+yz+zx)}{2} \geq \sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1-x^2y^2}{2+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: inequality

If $x, y, z$ are positive real numbers with the property $ xy, yz, zx \leq 1 $, then prove that $$ \frac{3-(xy+yz+zx)}{2} \geq \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1-x^2y^2}{2+x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: By that sum, you mean $\sum_{\text{cyc}}$ or $\sum_{\text{sym}}$ by any chance?

Comment: It's cyclic sum! :D

Comment: Are you sure about the $y^x$, it makes it ugly... Bernoulli's inequality may be useful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.se. Please give more details on how you encountered the problem and any attempts you made on the problem by editting the question. It'd make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Oh no! There is $ y^2 $not $y^x$..Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Use AM-GM to get: 
$$RHS = \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1-x^2y^2}{2+x^2+y^2} \le \sum_{cyc}\frac{1-x^2y^2}{2+2xy}= \frac12\sum_{cyc}(1-xy) = LHS $$